# large websocket packets not working with ie11

Tags: websocket, ethernet

I have a websocket server written using libwebsockets translating UDP to/from json so a web page can send/receive arbitrary UDP messages. A 1k UDP packet translates to about 3k of (suitably escaped) json. This works fine in chrome but ie11 reports an invalid packet. I can break it up and reassemble it on arrival but is there a better way?

Comment: have u moved any further? I posted the problem at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/11a05edf-b4fa-4c26-a2a8-c1061a64cd36/websocket-connection-breaks-for-larger-packets?forum=iewebdevelopment and at http://libwebsockets.org/trac/libwebsockets/ticket/73

Comment: Hi, in the end I broke down the messages and reassembled them. I assumed they arrive in order and haven't had any problems. I the message size was 10 bytes. Adrian